# BizTalk Bam Aggregation throws OLE DB Provider error

Tags: sql-server, oledb, biztalk, biztalk-bam

I am trying to access BAM URL in Intranet. I have hosted BAM in one server and it works fine there.

When I try accessing the BAM (http://servername/BAM) outside the server but within the intranet, I am getting following error while I try to see the aggregations.

Error:

> The query could not be processed:
>   Errors in the OLE DB provider.
>   Could not connect to the redirector.
>  Ensure that the SQLBrowser
>   service is running on the 'SERVERNAME' server.
>  Errors in the OLE DB
>   provider.
>  An error occurred while named instance information was being
>   retrieved from the SQLBrowser service on the 'SERVERNAME' server.

Activity search works fine though.

My sqlBrower services are up and running fine.

Comment: Seems like it's probably a permissions issue..  Are you using the same username outside the server as in?

Comment: Its the same user. @DanField: Is there a way that I could debug it. can you suggest any tools I could use..maybe

Comment: try https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917670.aspx